# Why button returns null when nested in an empty form using querySelector

Tags: javascript, html

When the button is nested in a form:

```
    <div>
        <form action="/">
            <h1>Form</h1>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="nameField" placeholder="Full name">
                <input type="number" name="Phone" id="phoneField" placeholder="Phone number">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="itemField" placeholder="item">
                <input type="date" name="name" id="dateField" placeholder="Date">
            </div>
            <button class="button" id="saveButton">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>

<script src="./index.js"></script>
```

it will always return null if I am trying to click the button **unless I filled in all textfields in this form**.

```
//index.js

const nameTextField = document.querySelector("#nameField");
const phoneTextField = document.querySelector("#phoneField");
const itemTextField = document.querySelector("#itemField");
const dateTextField = document.querySelector("#dateField");
const saveBt = document.querySelector("#saveButton");

saveBt.addEventListener("click", function () {
  const name = nameTextField.value;
  const phone = phoneTextField.value;
  const item = itemTextField.value;
  const date = dateTextField.value;
});
```

According to [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

> The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

Why it is unable to locate the button here?

Comment: are you calling it before it is rendered to the page

Comment: I don't think so. The .js script is loaded after the <div> tho

Comment: Is the form added dynamically?

Comment: You forget to add `type="button"` to your button, so the form is submited before

Comment: Yes adding `type="button"`  fixed my issue, but why this is the case?